# XSLT 2.0 library for C++

Tags: c++, xml, xslt, c++11, xslt-2.0

Are there any good XSLT libraries for C++ which support the 2.0 standard?
I've found several libraries but all of them had no implementation for XSLT 2.0.

Comment: As far as I know, the only implementations of XSLT 2.0 are Java implementations.

Comment: and there are no C++ bindings for it?

Comment: `XQilla` says it is in `Alpha` stage for `XSLT 2.0` support: http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/XSLT2

Comment: You may give try to XQilla, I know for sure it support XSLT 2.0 but i think it support it partially I am not sure about your use case so its worth to give it a try! http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/HomePage

Comment: There's is partial support for XSLT 2.0 in QT: [QtXmlPatterns](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/xmlprocessing.html#xslt-2-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows there is [AltovaXML](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) which according to http://manual.altova.com/AltovaXML/altovaxmlcommunity/ can be used with "Programming languages such as C++ or any other that supports the COM interface.".

Comment: And for *nix systems? Do you know of something?

Comment: I think Intel has a C or C++ implementation of XSLT 2.0 too but it is only available as part of their SOA web server and I am not even sure on which platforms that is available. There was also an attempt to upgrade libxslt to XSLT 2.0 but I think it failed to find funding.

Comment: thank you guys. I need in on *nix ;)